# Yasnippet: How to expand on " or" but not on "-or"

Tags: emacs, yasnippet

Title says it, is it possible to alter yasnippets behavior so that it is not possible to expand on "-or" but it is possible to expand on "[newline]or" or "[tab]or" only?

I would like this because I am trying to expand my yasnippets automatically when expansion is possible, and there is only ever confliction when I am writing variable names.

Comment: You may want to ask the developers of yasnippet directly.

Comment: I guess you could use the [`condition` directive](http://capitaomorte.github.com/yasnippet/snippet-development.html#condition-snippet-condition) to specify this. Should it expand in all cases but when there is a hyphen before or?

Comment: I would say yes, but once this behavior can be altered maybe more advanced things become possible.

Comment: I believe indeed that with your link this can be solved.

Comment: @Dualinity I guess one just needs a line of lisp code that returns true if the character before the yasnippet key that is directly before the point is a not a hyphen and otherwise false. One could even do the ugly hack of checking if the character three steps back from the point is not a hyphen.

Comment: In the example, `python-in-string/comment` is given as an example to exclude python mode, but this does not even work for any other mode... (obviously switching python to emacs-lisp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution here: 
http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_tip_yasnippet_expand_whole_hyphenated_word.html

There is variable `(defvar yas-key-syntaxes (list "w" "w_" "w_." "w_.()" "^ ")..)`, which controls kinds of expansions. `"w"` means that `"-or" is expanded as separate "or".

If

```
(setq yas-key-syntaxes '("w_" "w_." "w_.()" "^ "))
```

then `"-or"` is expanded as complex expression `"<some>-or"` only. But `" or"` is expanded as usually.

So, `"buffer-substring"` will be expanded only if there is file `buffer-substring.yasnippet` with content

```
# contributor: Xah Lee (XahLee.org)
# name: buffer-substring
# key: buffer-substring
# --
(buffer-substring START$0 END)
```

But with `"w"` keyword `"buffer-substring"` will be expanded as `substring.yasnippet`.

If there is additional string `# key: bs` in file `buffer-substring.yasnippet` then `"buffer-substring"` won't be expanded at all. (For Version: 0.8.0)