# Easiest Regexp for words-with-dashes-but-no-whitespace

Tags: emacs, elisp

What is the most convenient regexp for selecting text like "words-with-dashes-but-no-whitespace", when the goal is to select just this but no whitespace?

I used `(search-forward-regexp "\\s-")` but I believe this could be easier.

I mainly would like this for selecting the word at point including dashes, and using buffer-substring-no-properties to set it as a variable.

EDIT: Answer was given by [artscan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1937596/artscan) in a comment. Using (current-word) solves this.

But now this: how to delete this `(current-word)` including-dashes-that-is?

I use so far `(delete-backward-char (string-width (current-word))`

Comment: Try `(current-word)` - it returns your text at point.

Comment: That is exactly it. `(word-at-point)` only does the word, but this does it all.

Comment: Btw, function `(current-word)` is based on syntax like "w" and "w_", which is used for parsing snippets, see my answer to your question http://stackoverflow.com/a/14416552/1937596

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the second question, try:

```
(let ((bounds (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'symbol)))
   (when bounds
     (delete-region (car bounds) (cdr bounds))))
```

It's less dependent on point location than `(delete-backward-char ...)`.

Comment: Excellent. I was afraid it wouldn't work for function names, but it does. This is nice.